# Gigabyte Aero 15x Ubuntu 18.04 Some Fn keys not working

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, brightness, function-keys

I have an Aero 15x v8 where I installed ubuntu 18.04. I'm facing a problem using some Fn keys like changing brightness or disabling Wifi but some other Fn keys work like changing volume.

I tried updating the drivers, changing the grub conf

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Unfortunately nothing seems to work.